# NoMethodError - Undefined Method - Pulling a name out of an ID in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model-view-controller

I have a landlord model and in the table there is a field for listing_agent_id. There is also an agent model where all of their info is stored. In the index view I am trying to us `<%= landlord.listing_agent.name` but keep getting an error. I have defined agents in my landlords_controller, but it still doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated.

Landlord Index:

```
<tbody>
  <% @landlords.each do |landlord| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= landlord.listing_agent.name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Landlords Controller:

```
def index
   @landlords = Landlord.all
end

def new
   @landlord = Landlord.new
   @agents = Agent.employees.order(first_name: :asc)
end
```

Landlord Model:

```
class Landlord < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :landlord_addresses
end
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord does not "automagically" create an association just because you have a `*_id` column. There are just two many possibilities for that to be remotely useful.

To setup an association between `Landlord` and `Agent` you would do:

```
class Landlord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listing_agent, class_name: 'Agent'
                             inverse_of: :landlord 
  # use inverse_of: :landlords if the relation is one to many.
end

class Agent < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :landlord, inverse_of: :listing_agent
  # or
  has_many :landlords, inverse_of: :listing_agent
end
```

The `class_name: 'Agent'` option is needed because ActiveRecord cannot deduce the class from the name of the association. [`inverse_of`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations) helps avoid inconsistencies by keeping a single object in memory.